# Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator fails to install

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I tried installing updates for Visual Studio 2015, but the web platform installer fails to install the Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator.

Here's a link to the log file:
http://pastebin.com/JPAaJTHv

Comment: Can you try to install using offline installer from here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/downloads/. Just search for "Azure Storage Emulator" on this page.

Comment: This one managed to install successfully. Thank you!